# How can I use REST API to filter using multiple columns in UserInformationList

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, javascript, sharepoint-addin, jsom

How can I **filter multiple columns in REST API** using Name/Username when running GET request to UserInformationList?

Here is my **Query:**

```
 var getPeoplePickerSuggestion = function(searchKey) {
        var userSearchSuggestionEndpoint = "/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/UserInformationList?$select=Id,Name,UserName,WorkEmail&$filter=substringof('" + searchKey + "',Name)";
        return baseSvc.getRequest(userSearchSuggestionEndpoint);
    }
```

Comment: What are all the columns you want to apply filters?

Comment: Have you tried adding another condition?  Should be able to simply do `"$filter=substringof('" + value1 + "', Key1) and substringof('" + value2 + "', Key2)"`

Comment: You need to know how filter works. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/990131/CRUD-Operation-to-List-Using-SharePoint-Rest-API

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please see the below [example](http://www.infopulse.com/blog/working-with-sharepoint-foundation-rest-interface-using-odata-and-jquery/), you can use the "and" operator, to meet multiple conditions,

```
  http://{server_name}/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/UserInformationList?$filter=((ContentType eq 'Person') 
  and (substringof(Name,'{query}')))&$orderby=Name
```

Also, shared by Atish, on the following [page](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/990131/CRUD-Operation-to-List-Using-SharePoint-Rest-API), it shows you multiple other operators, you can use in your filter, such  as,

You may notice that I have used a query operator like ‘eq’ in above URL. Now let’s see what are the other query operators available, for strings, numeric, and datetimes.

[image]

Comment: Keep in mind you need to escape ' like: substringof(Name,'Bob's Burger') -> substringof(Name,'Bob''s Burger')

Answer (score 0):

i ended up with query below, works fine for me now, and i can search on LoginName, Title, or Email.

```
`var userSearchSuggestionEndpoint = "/_api/web/SiteUsers?$filter=(substringof('" + searchKey + "',LoginName) or substringof('" + searchKey + "',Title) or substringof('" + searchKey + "',Email))";
        return baseSvc.getRequest(userSearchSuggestionEndpoint);`
```